Why does Redis 7 mget operations cause increased timeouts
I am trying to migrate my service from Redis 4 version to Redis 7, and after deployment it seems that there has been a spike in Read Time Out Errors only specific to mget operations. In Redis 4 also there were Read Timed outs, but the numbers were very less in comparison to Redis 7. Is there any difference in configuration of mget in Redis 4 and 7.
FYI, I am using redis.clients:jedis:4.4.6 . How do I solve this issue?
org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.collectResults(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:266)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.executeMultiKeyCommand(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:301)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterStringCommands.mGet(JedisClusterStringCommands.java:118)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.mGet(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:312)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.lambda$multiGet$7(DefaultValueOperations.java:193)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:373)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:97)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.multiGet(DefaultValueOperations.java:193)
at com.myservice.service.impl.RedisService.lambda$getValues$2(RedisServiceImpl.java:106)
at io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeTimer.record(CompositeTimer.java:69)
at com.myservice.service.impl.RedisServiceImpl.getValues(RedisServiceImpl.java:106)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor84.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704)

